# importing a git-submodule into a golang gae app

Tags: google-app-engine, go, openid

I have a submodule in my golang google-app-engine project that I would like to add to my path.

```
$ ls ./openid/src/openid
discover.go             integration          verify.go
discover_test.go        nonce_store.go       xrds.go
discovery_cache.go      nonce_store_test.go  xrds_test.go
fake_getter_test.go     normalizer.go        yadis_discovery.go
getter.go               normalizer_test.go   yadis_discovery_test.go
html_discovery.go       redirect.go
html_discovery_test.go  redirect_test.go
```

In the example code for this package, it imports "openid".  I'm new to golang's import rules, and I can't for the life of me figure out what I need to put in the import statement of my main file to import this package.  I've tried "openid/src/openid", "myapp/openid/src/openid", etc.  Can someone provide some clarification of how this works?  Or do I need to actually modify the app.yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

"[Organizing Go code](http://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code)" mentions:

> An import path is the string with which users import a package.
>   It specifies the directory (relative to `$GOROOT/src/pkg` or `$GOPATH/src`) in which the package's source code resides.

So make sure to use an import statement referring to a path which exists in your  `$GOPATH/src`. (`GOPATH` being your "workspace", in which you have namespaces, as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCsL89YtqCs)).
Also make sure you build first `openid/src/openid` sources. And install it (`go install`).

As [detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17541170/6309):

- Import paths can be be globally unique.
- In conjunction with `GOPATH`, import path can be translated unambiguously to a directory path.
- Any directory path under `GOPATH` can be unambiguously translated to an import path.